# My cloudflare settings are all configured but not working

Tags: linux, dns, ipv4, cloudflare, a-records

So, I am using CloudFlare at the moment for my DNS records. I have my team speak server A-Record at ts.servername.net and pointing to my ip 100.100.100.100, and all my other A-Records are pointing to exactly where they should be and activated.

They were working previously but all of a sudden for the last week or so, we have had to use our IPv4 ts server ip in order to connect instead of our server name, why is it doing this even though everything is setup and was already working?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend opening a [support ticket](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-) with specific details & we can help.

Please note that we can only proxy web traffic records going over [certain ports](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-) like 80 and 443.